# find data with arrays of ids in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a array list from another example but this don’t work for me, maybe is because i need use `ObjectId()`’ but i don’t know how i will can parse this array, too i don’t know if is possibly  get only once param (username) and not the full array?

the code is this:

```
var list =      ["5883d387971bb840b7399130","5883d389971bb840b7399131","5883d38a971bb840b7399132"]
.find({ _id: {$in : list}},{username:1})
```

can you help and say me how i need create the query ?   thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is correct except you need to wrap your ids inside `ObjectId` using map.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

var list = ["5883d387971bb840b7399130","5883d389971bb840b7399131","5883d38a971bb840b7399132"]

db.collectionName('newCollection').find({ _id: {$in : list.map( (id) =>  ObjectId(id))}}, {userName:1, _id:0})
```

Comment: i have this error from node : “ObjectId is not defined” but i import from mongo and work !

Comment: var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;